# concatenate an integer to the url in python giving error

Tags: python

I would like to parse through a set of URLs, so I would like to concatenate an integer where the page id is changing like this.

In the middle of the URL there is `%count%` but it seems not working.  How can I concatenate it?

```
count=2
while (count < pages):
    mech = Browser()
    url = 'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s'% count %'%s?rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491'
    url = int(raw_input(url))

    mech = Browser()

    page = mech.open(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    print url
    for thediv in soup.findAll('li',{'class':' ilo2'}):
        links = thediv.find('a')
        links = links['href']
        print links
    count = count+1
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Final Url Format

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491
```

Comment: try it : 'string %s' % str(your_value)

Comment: Humm your code is not properly indented, could you edit your question to correct this ?

Comment: The whole `url` assignment is wacky. You can interpolate without a cast like `url = 'stuff%dmore stuff' % count` but multiple `%` operations don't make sense, at least not here.

Comment: Also, what's with the `url = int(raw_input(url))` thing? Where is the input supposed to come from and why do you want it to be a number?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you gave us a clue as to how you want the final url to look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have urlencoded entities in your string (`%3A` etc.).  You might try using `{}` syntax instead:

```
url = 'http://.....{}...{}...'.format(first_arg, second_arg)
```

then you'll see any other issues in the string also..

Answer (score 2):

The `%` operator does not work like that in python.

Here is how you should use it :

```
url = 'http://....../ref=sr_pg_%s?rh=.............' % (count, )
```

As you already have `%` symbols in your URL pattern, you should begin by doubling them so they won't be seen as placeholders by python :

```
url = 'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s?rh=n%%3A2858778011%%2Cp_drm_rights%%3APurchase%%7CRental%%2Cn%%3A2858905011%%2Cp_n_date%%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491' % (count, )
```

That being said, there is python module dedicated to parse and create URL, it is named urllib and you can find its documentation here : https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Note that OP will need to double the other % characters in the url string to prevent them being interpreted as string placeholders.

Comment: I'm wrong about using count "before", I'll edit my answer. The count value is available from the start of the script.

Comment: If you can expalin it using the url i have ,it would be great thank you

Comment: Answer edited to warn about doubling placeholders and using the OP url

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to keep the string as is (not inserting a variable value inside), the problem would be due to the fact that you use single quotes `'` to delimit your string that contains itself quotes inside. You can use instead double quotes:

```
url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s'% count %'%s?rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491"
```

A better solution is escaping the quotes:

```
url = 'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s\'% count %\'%s?rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491'
```

Comment: I'm not sure... I think he wants to put the `count` value in the ref=sr_pg_COUNT argument of the url.

Comment: ah, that's in fact possible!

Comment: @GhislainLeveque So I updated my answer to precise what is addressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse or edit URLs using raw strings, one should use the dedicated module, `urllib2` (or `urllib`, depending on the python version).

Here is a simple example, using the OP's url :

```
from urllib2 import urlparse
original_url = (
    """http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A2858778011%2"""
    """Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date"""
    """%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491""")
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(original_url)
```

This returns something like that :

```
ParseResult(
    scheme='http', netloc='www.amazon.com', path='/s/ref=sr_pg_2',
    params='',
    query='rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491', fragment='')
```

Then we edit the path part of the url

```
scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = parsed
path = '/s/ref=sr_pg_%d' % (count, )
```

And we "unparse" the url :

```
new_url = urlparse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
```

And we have a new url with path edited :

```
'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_423?rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_drm_rights%3APurchase%7CRental%2Cn%3A2858905011%2Cp_n_date%3A2693527011&page=3&sort=csrank&ie=UTF8&qid=1403073491'
```